# Find the XOR of every other number in a given range

Tags: algorithms, bit-strings

Lets say that R=15 and L=8, then how can I efficiently find:

```
15 XOR 13 XOR 11 XOR 9
```

If R=20 and L=10, then it would be:

```
20 XOR 18 XOR 16 XOR 14 XOR 12 XOR 10
```

$1<=L<=R<=10^{15}$

This might be similiar [Finding XOR of all even numbers from n to m](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558404/finding-xor-of-all-even-numbers-from-n-to-m) but that only covers even numbers. If R is odd then it will be all odd numbers from R to L.

I asked this question on StackOverflow previously but it was marked as duplicate and the problem wasn't exactly the same as this one.

Comment: This question is essentially the same. Only the least significant bit may be different, and is determined by the number of odd values being XORed together. ```15 XOR 13 XOR 11 XOR 9 = 14 XOR 12 XOR 10 XOR 8```